# What's a word for something half-submerged?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'd like to briefly describe a number of large objects that are half-submerged in a swamp, and nothing quite fits so far. Just "sunken" or the like might work in a pinch, but I thought I'd ask in case someone knows a word that quickly communicates that the objects are also clearly visible above the water.

Comment: Is there a problem with _half-submerged_?

Comment: For single-word-requests you are asked (if you look at the tag info) to provide a sample sentence of how the word will be used. I think in this instance that would be specially useful.

Comment: *Half-buried* is the equivalent with land, so *half-submerged* or *half-underwater*  makes sense. I do wonder if there's a specialized marine term.

Comment: 1920 was a watershed year for "submerged".  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sunken+log%2Csubmerged+log&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Semisubmerged' appears to be a valid word, but not, I would say, a very elegant one.

> - The semisubmersible rig has an elevated drilling platform on top of a floating structure which is semisubmerged in the water.

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/semisubmersible-rig)]

There are words for movement half in, half out of, water - such as wallowing or floundering.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth    'The semisubmersible rig has an elevated drilling platform on top of a floating structure which is _semisubmerged_ in the water.' I missed it, first time round, myself.

Comment: Good spot. It's semisubmerged in the small print. (I wonder why they feel it suitable to be used in an example but not to be listed?)

Comment: 'Twas only dredged up for this exercise. After today, it will be sunk without trace.

Comment: Semisubmerged is usually a technical term and implies, to me at least, that the thing was designed for that mode. I get the impression that the OP's objects are incongruous with the swamp.

Answer (score 1):

[Wading](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wading) can mean partially immersed, but it implies motion.

> ... as though they had begun wading ...

Answer (score -1):

7 years later, I would add basking to this list.

We must grow our language. I think of hundreds of words that need to exist daily. We must give this task to the French and then we will anglicize.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A cabin is basking in the swamp? Isn't it "basking in the *sun*"? The rest of your answer is an original way to meet the minimum number of characters but it's irrelevant, questionable, and in the end completely unhelpful to any visitor who lands on this page.